# E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, update-manager

I have been trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 but the `sudo do-release-upgrade` is failing with "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading." message.

This seems to be because `sudo apt update` completes albeit with following error messages:

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                       
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                  
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                         
Hit:5 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                           
Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                          
Hit:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial InRelease                                                   
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
Hit:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates InRelease                                          
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                           
Hit:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports InRelease                                         
Hit:12 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                  
Hit:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security InRelease                                          
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main amd64 Packages                                         
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main i386 Packages     
Get:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main Translation-en [568 kB]
Get:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [733 kB]     
Get:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [409 kB]            
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease              
Ign:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe i386 Packages                 
Get:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe Translation-en [4,354 kB]
Get:24 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security InRelease [7,515 B]
Hit:24 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security InRelease          
Get:25 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,410 kB]
Get:26 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,448 kB]                
Ign:27 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:28 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Get:29 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted Translation-en [2,908 B]
Get:30 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [186 B]
Ign:31 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:32 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Get:33 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main Translation-en [461 kB]
Get:34 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-updates InRelease [7,475 B]
Hit:34 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-updates InRelease                         
Get:35 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [326 kB]       
Get:36 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [252 kB]
Ign:37 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:38 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Get:39 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [358 kB]
Get:40 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [280 kB]
Get:41 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [437 kB]
Ign:42 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:43 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Get:44 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,272 B]
Get:45 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [157 B]
Ign:46 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:47 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Get:48 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports/main Translation-en [4,456 B]
Get:49 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]
Get:50 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Get:51 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [194 B]
Ign:52 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:53 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Get:54 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main Translation-en [360 kB]
Get:55 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [93.8 kB]
Get:56 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [111 kB]
Ign:57 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:58 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Get:59 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted Translation-en [2,152 B]
Get:60 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [200 B]
Ign:61 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:62 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Get:63 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe Translation-en [225 kB]
Get:64 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [130 kB]
Get:65 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [206 kB]
Ign:66 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                         
Ign:67 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages                                                          
Get:68 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en [2,672 B]                                               
Get:69 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]                                        
Get:70 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [2,638 B]                                           
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                                        
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main i386 Packages                                                                         
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe amd64 Packages                                                                    
Ign:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe i386 Packages                                                                     
Ign:27 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                  
Ign:28 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted i386 Packages                                                                   
Ign:31 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages                                                                
Ign:32 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main i386 Packages                                                                 
Ign:37 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages                                                            
Ign:38 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages                                                             
Ign:42 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages                                                          
Ign:43 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages                                                           
Ign:46 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages                                                              
Ign:47 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports/main i386 Packages                                                               
Ign:52 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main amd64 Packages                                                               
Ign:53 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main i386 Packages                                                                
Ign:57 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages                                                         
Ign:58 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages                                                          
Ign:61 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages                                                           
Ign:62 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe i386 Packages                                                            
Ign:66 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                         
Ign:67 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages                                                          
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                                        
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main i386 Packages                                                                         
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe amd64 Packages                                                                    
Ign:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe i386 Packages                                                                     
Ign:27 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                  
Ign:28 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted i386 Packages                                                                   
Ign:31 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages                                                                
Ign:32 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main i386 Packages                                                                 
Ign:37 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages                                                            
Ign:38 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages                                                             
Ign:42 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages                                                          
Ign:43 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages                                                           
Ign:46 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages                                                              
Ign:47 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports/main i386 Packages                                                               
Ign:52 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main amd64 Packages                                                               
Ign:53 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main i386 Packages                                                                
Ign:57 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages                                                         
Ign:58 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages                                                          
Ign:61 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages                                                           
Ign:62 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe i386 Packages                                                            
Ign:66 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                         
Ign:67 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages                                                          
Err:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main i386 Packages                                                                         
Ign:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe amd64 Packages                                                                    
Ign:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe i386 Packages                                                                     
Ign:27 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                  
Ign:28 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/restricted i386 Packages                                                                   
Err:31 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages                                                                
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
Ign:32 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main i386 Packages                                                                 
Ign:37 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages                                                            
Ign:38 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages                                                             
Ign:42 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages                                                          
Ign:43 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages                                                           
Err:46 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages                                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
Ign:47 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-backports/main i386 Packages                                                               
Err:52 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main amd64 Packages                                                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
Ign:53 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main i386 Packages                                                                
Ign:57 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages                                                         
Ign:58 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages                                                          
Ign:61 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages                                                           
Ign:62 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/universe i386 Packages                                                            
Ign:66 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                         
Ign:67 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages                                                          
Fetched 3,262 kB in 10s (298 kB/s)                                                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I checked using browser that URLs for which the command failed do not exit. However, I am not sure how I can modify my `/etc/apt/sources.list` to remove these errors. I had to basically comment everything in my source.list to get rid of them. But I am not sure that is the correct solution as it seems to just disable all updates altogether.

Here is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial main universe restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-updates main universe restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-updates main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-backports main restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-backports main restricted multiverse universe

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-security universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-security multiverse
#deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main multiverse universe
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial restricted multiverse universe main
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe multiverse
# deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main
# deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
```

uname -a output:
`Linux a-thinkpad-e470 4.15.0-142-generic #146~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 13 09:27:15 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

dpkg --print-architecture:
`amd64`

dpkg --print-foreign-architectures:
`i386`

Please let me know how do I resolve this.

Comment: Hello. You are trying to upgrade from an EOL version. The links are gone. Once EOL they remove the links. See this page for some official help. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: @David Oh, okay! ThThe link you shared suggests I update my source.list with `old-releases.ubuntu.com` links. Do I disable all other URLs in my current list then? Also, it suggests I upgrade the kernel before running sudo `do-release-upgrade`. Is this mandatory? I assume kernel version will also be updated with the `do-release-upgrade`? Thanks!

Comment: Relating to 16.04 yes. Myself I would not mess with the kernel.

Comment: May of your sources are invalid... and need correcting.. eg. `http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main amd64` """   *amd64* is **not** a port so why are/were you trying to get details from there?  That line was *invalid* even before 16.04 was *end of standard support*.

Comment: FYI: There is no longer a supported upgrade path from 16.04.  The release upgrade was available starting with 18.04.1 which was released in July of 2018 and the window closed nearly three years later when support ended in April 2021. Users are expected to upgrade before a release becomes unsupported. Release upgrade may still work even though it's unsupported, and is more likely to be successful if you sign up for ESM. However in many cases, once a release becomes unsupported it's often better to reinstall a currently supported release.

Comment: I have tried upgrading using the steps mentioned for EOL upgrades in `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades#Upgrading` . But adding `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` to source.list throws `E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.` Is there no way to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 using `do-release-upgrade` ? I prefer not to re-install since data and config on my PC might get disturbed.

Comment: Please read the question @pLumo linked about upgrading from an unsupported release. If you truly value your data and configs, you'd have backups (and backups of the backups) Backups are especially essential before you begin a release upgrade, supported or not.

Comment: Interesting. I see, that `xenial` is still at [archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial), but not in [old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/). Anyways, I'd backup and reinstall. Too much changed from 16.04 to make an update useful, and you need to update to 18.04, which will also be EOL by next year, then 20.04 and then 22.04, which will come out in 2 weeks from now. If this is not a production system, I would already [install 22.04 Beta](https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/).